# Set gdb breakpoint by address with gdb python

Tags: gdb, breakpoint

into GDB python I tried `gdb.Breakpoint('0xaaaa')`

I got error

`Function 0xaaaa is not defided  . Breakpoint 5(0xaaaa) pending`

and  the program not break at this address.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to prefix the address with a `'*'`, like when using `break`.

For example:

```
(gdb) python
>gdb.Breakpoint('*0x080487ff')
>end
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80487ff
(gdb)
```